# How to get specific details from a tag web scraping?

Tags: python, html, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape specific details as a `list` from a page using `BeautifulSoup` in python.

```html
<p class="collapse text in" id="list_2">
    <big>•</big>
    &nbsp;car
    <br>
    <big>•</big>
    &nbsp;bike&nbsp;
    <br> 
    <span id="list_hidden_2" class="inline_hidden collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
        <big>•</big>
        &nbsp;bus
        <br>
        <big>•</big>
        &nbsp;train
        <br><br> 
    </span>
    <span>...</span>
    <a data-id="list" href="#list_hidden_2" class="link_sm link_toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
        aria-expanded="true"></a>
</p>
```

I need a `list` with every text contained in the `<p>`
like this,

```py
list = ['car', 'bike', 'bus', 'train']
```

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

p_tag = soup.find("p", {"id":"list_2"})
list = p_tag.text.strip()
print(list)
```

output:

```
• car• bike
• bus• train
```

How to convert this as a `list` like, `list = ['car', 'bike', 'bus', 'train']`

Comment: <p class="collapse text in" id="list_2">
    <big>•</big>
    &nbsp;car
    <br>
    <big>•</big>
    &nbsp;bike&nbsp;
    <br> 
    <span id="list_hidden_2" class="inline_hidden collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
        <big>•</big>
        &nbsp;bus
        <br>
        <big>•</big>
        &nbsp;train
        <br><br> 
    </span>
    <span>...</span>
    <a data-id="list" href="#list_hidden_2" class="link_sm link_toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
        aria-expanded="true"></a>
</p>

Comment: Try doing output.split("•")

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *Avoid using `python` reserved terms ([`keywords`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling)), this could have unwanted effects on the results of your code.*

---

There are several ways to get your goal. I would recommend to work on your strategy selecting the elements. Select all `<big>` first and than pick its [`next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
[e.next_sibling.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.select('big')]
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<p class="collapse text in" id="list_2">
    <big>•</big>
    &nbsp;car
    <br>
    <big>•</big>
    &nbsp;bike&nbsp;
    <br> 
    <span id="list_hidden_2" class="inline_hidden collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
        <big>•</big>
        &nbsp;bus
        <br>
        <big>•</big>
        &nbsp;train
        <br><br> 
    </span>
    <span>...</span>
    <a data-id="list" href="#list_hidden_2" class="link_sm link_toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
        aria-expanded="true"></a>
</p>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

item_list = [e.next_sibling.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.select('big')]
print(item_list)
```

###### Output

```
['car', 'bike', 'bus', 'train']
```

Comment: Hi HedgeHog, This approach works, I just tried it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Even I thought the similar way as [@HedgeHog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76206364/14172167) did. The alternative way is also to select the `<br>` tag and get the text prior to it using [`previous_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling).

You can modify your scraping code as:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

p_tag = soup.find("p", {"id":"list_2"})
output = [p.previous_sibling.text.strip() for p in p_tag.select('br')]
print(*output)
```

Output:

```
car bike bus train
```

Comment: Of course, the other way around works as well, but for the sake of completeness, the `list` consists of an additional empty element that results from the `<br><br>`.  The same can theoretically happen with my solution approach if the structure behaves differently from the example and no further checks take place that would catch these circumstances. ultimately, I had estimated the probability of deviations coming from `<big>` to be lower. It would probably be more precise to check for the `NavigableString` in both cases.

Comment: Yes.I agree with you.